# How find this $a^3+b^3+c^3-20(a+3)(b+3)(c+3)=2013$ equation integer solution

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

if $a,b,c\in Z$,and $a\le b\le c$
and such 
$$\begin{cases}
a+b+c=-3\\
a^3+b^3+c^3-20(a+3)(b+3)(c+3)=2013
\end{cases}$$
Find the value  $3a+b+2c=?$

my try
$$a+b+c=-3\Longrightarrow (a+1)+(b+1)+(c+1)=0$$
so
$$(a+1)^3+(b+1)^3+(c+1)^3=3(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)$$

This problem is from a few month ago comption.

then I can't,Thank you

Comment: Hint: How much is $(a+b+c)^3$ ? Expand the parentheses using the [multinomial formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Example), and then employ it to drastically reduce your second equation.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche,Yes,But this problem have no solve it

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche,Thank you,I have add it

Comment: @nanchangjian You have a lot of unanswered posts, **please** consider acceoting an answer or answering them yourself, or all of them will be left in the to-do queue forever..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)
and [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_power_sums_in_terms_of_elementary_symmetric_polynomials).

For three variables, the basic idea is that *any* symmetric expression in $a,b,$ and $c$ can be written in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials $s_1 = a + b + c$, $s_2 = ab + bc + ca$, and $s_3 = abc$.  So for example:
\begin{align*}
(a + 3)(b + 3)(c + 3) &= abc + 3(ab + bc + ca) + 9(a + b + c) + 27 \\
&= 27 + 9s_1 + 3s_2 + s_3 \\
a^3 + b^3 + c^3 &= (a + b + c)^3 - 6abc\\
&\quad - (3a^2b + 3ab^2 + 3a^2c + 3ac^2 + 3bc^2 + 3cb^2) \\
&= (a + b + c)^3 - 6abc\\
&\quad - 3[(a + b + c)(ab + bc + ca) - 3abc] \\
&= s_1^3 -3s_1s_2 + 3s_3
\end{align*}
With the above substitutions, your equations become
\begin{align*}
s_1 &= -3 \\
s_1^3 - 3s_1s_2 + 3s_3 - 20(27 + 9s_1 + 3s_2 + s_3) &= 2013
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
-27 + 9s_2 + 3s_3 - 20(3s_2 + s_3) &= 2013 \\
-51s_2 - 17s_3 &= 2040 \\
-3s_2 - s_3 &= 120
\end{align*}
Let $s_3 = 3k$.  Then $s_1 = -3$ and $s_2 = -40 - k$.  $a,b,c$ are the roots of the polynomial
$$
x^3 - s_1x^2 + s_2x - s_3 = x^3 + 3x^2 - (k + 40)x - 3k
$$
so $a,b,c$ satisfy
$$
(x + 3)(x^2 - k - 40) = -120
$$
Now $a \le b \le c$ and $a + b + c = -3$ implies that $c \ge -1$, so $c + 3 \ge 2$.
The above implies that $c + 3 \Big| 120$.
After we factor out $x-c$, the remaining polynomial will be $x^2 + (c+3)x + c^2 + 3c - k - 40 = x^2 + (c+3)x + 3k/c $.

Massive casework follows:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
c + 3 & c & c^2 & k + 40 - c^2 & k & x^2 + (c+3)x + 3k/c \\
\hline
2 & -1 & 1 & 60 & 21 & x^2 + 2x - 63\\
3 & 0 & 0 & 40 & 0 & x^2 + 3x - 40 \\
4 & 1 & 1 & 30 & -9 & x^2 + 4x - 27 \\
5 & 2 & 4 & 24 & -12 & x^2 + 5x - 18 \\
6 & 3 & 9 & 20 & -11 & x^2 + 6x - 11 \\
8 & 5 & 25 & 15 & 0 & x^2 + 8x \\
10 & 7 & 49 & 12 & 21 & x^2 + 10x + 9 \\
12 & 9 & 81 & 10 & 51 & x^2 + 12x + 17 \\
15 & 12 & 144 & 8 & 112 & x^2 + 15x + 28 \\
20 & 17 & 289 & 6 & 255 & x^2 + 20x + 45 \\
24 & 21 & 441 & 5 & 406 & x^2 + 24x + 58 \\
30 & 27 & 729 & 4 & 693 & x^2 + 30x + 77 \\
40 & 37 & 1369 & 3 & 1332 & x^2 + 40x + 108 \\
60 & 57 & 3249 & 2 & 3211 & x^2 + 60x + 169 \\
120 & 117 & 13689 & 1 & 13650 & x^2 + 120x + 350 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
c & x^2 + (c+3)x + c^2 + 3k/c & \text{Factored: } (x-a)(x-b) & a & b \\
\hline
-1 & x^2 + 2x - 63 & (x+9)(x-7) & -9 & 7 \\
0 & x^2 + 3x - 40 & (x+8)(x-5) & -8 & 5 \\
1 & x^2 + 4x - 27 & --- \\
2 & x^2 + 5x - 18 & --- \\
3 & x^2 + 6x - 11 & --- \\
5 & x^2 + 8x & (x+8)x & -8 & 0 \\
7 & x^2 + 10x + 9 & (x+9)(x+1) & -9 & -1 \\
9 & x^2 + 12x + 17 & --- \\
12 & x^2 + 15x + 28 & --- \\
17 & x^2 + 20x + 45 & --- \\
21 & x^2 + 24x + 58 & --- \\
27 & x^2 + 30x + 77 & --- \\
37 & x^2 + 40x + 108 & --- \\
57 & x^2 + 60x + 169 & --- \\
117 & x^2 + 120x + 350 & --- \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
We see that the two solutions are $(a,b,c) = (-8,0,5)$ or $(-9,-1,7)$.  You can verify that both of these are indeed solutions, and in both cases,
$$
3a + b + 2c = 2(a + b + c) + (a - b) = -6 + (-8) = \boxed{-14}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Let's forget about $a\le b \le c$ for the moment.
$$a+b+c=-3$$
$$\implies (a+b+c)^3 =a^3+b^3+c^3+3(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)=-27$$
Let's substitute $a^3+b^3+c^3=x$, $(a+b)(b+c)(a+c)=y$.Then, we have that
$$x+20y=2013$$
$$x+3y=-27$$
$$\implies y=120$$
Let's sub $a+b=m,b+c=n,a+c=p$.Now we have
$$m+n+p=-6,$$
$$mnp=120$$
Since by an easy argument either all $m,n,p$ are even or only one of them is, and since $mnp=120$, they are all even, or one is a multiple of $8$. So let's sub again! $m=2r,n=2s,p=2t$.So
$$r+s+t=-3$$
$$rst=15$$
So we have $(r,s,t)=(-5,-1,3)$ and permutations, so a solution is $(a,b,c)=(-1,-9,7)$.

The other case
$$8r+s+t=-6$$
$$rst=15$$
So we have $(r,s,t)=(-1,-3,5)$  and $(a,b,c)=(-8,0,5)$.

**Remark:** I was running out of letters.